# Two bindParam in same string values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sorry in advance for my English.

I have a 'problem' with PDO bindParam.

```
$sql_fact_1 = "INSERT INTO factures_interventions (id_client, id_facture, id_cat, detail_intervention, prix_intervention, date_intervention, etat_intervention)
VALUES (:id_client, '0', '3', 'Renouvellement automatique annuel (:date_fin) du compte :compte', :tarif, :date_actuelle, '0' )";

$req = $bdd->prepare($sql_fact_1);

$req->bindParam('id_client', $client_1['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->bindParam('date_fin', $dateRenou, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam('compte', $compte_1['compte'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam('tarif', $resultat_form_1['tarif'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam('date_actuelle', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$req->execute();
$req->closeCursor();
```

The problem here

```
'Renouvellement automatique annuel (:date_fin) du compte :compte'
```

is that I am trying to enter two binds in a phrase but i get an error :

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```
'Renouvellement automatique annuel (':date_fin') du compte ':compte''
```

Like that, it works but i have quote in my row. :(

Like :

Renouvellement automatique annuel ('2022/09/01') du compte 'moncompte.fr'

How to remove quotes ?

Comment: You cannot have placeholders in the middle of the string value. Build up your string outside of the query, and insert the string itself.

Comment: Or use CONCAT to create the value out of static parts and placeholder values inside the query.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it's much better ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have parameters inside of quoted strings. You'll have to build up your string and insert that:

```
$sql_fact_1 = "INSERT INTO factures_interventions (id_client, id_facture, id_cat, detail_intervention, prix_intervention, date_intervention, etat_intervention)
VALUES (:id_client, '0', '3', :renouvellement, :tarif, :date_actuelle, '0' )";

$renouvellement = "Renouvellement automatique annuel ($dateRenou) du compte ".$compte_1['compte'];
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql_fact_1);

$req->bindParam('id_client', $client_1['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->bindParam('renouvellement', $renouvellement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam('tarif', $resultat_form_1['tarif'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam('date_actuelle', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed it's much better ^^